# RQ worker and process in background

Tags: python, background, queue, screen, rq

I'm using RQ to manage jobs into my application.

I launch the work with a python script but i want to just launch the worker and close the file and not have the script in run.

````
w = Worker([q], connection=redis_connection, name=queue)
w.work(max_idle_time=30000)```

Actually i have to use the script in a screen but i wanted to know how you manage the worker with RQ on your side ?
````

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336524/have-python-script-run-in-background-of-unix